# Data before start of table in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm parsing an Excel file that's a 20k row data table, using pandas. So far so good, but there's a tiny bit of metadata above the start of the table that I'd like to use too (the date the table was generated).

Currently if I don't skip any rows:

```
raw = pd.read_excel(datafile, sheetname=0, parse_cols="B, D:I")
```

The first few rows are just nans:

```
>>> raw.values[0]
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object)
```

I could open the file with something more basic like xlrd to get that data, but that requires loading the whole file into memory twice, something I'd rather not do.

Can pandas get at the data above the start of the table without re-importing the file?

Comment: try with the header parameter in that method. [You can check the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: @AmeyYadav No, that's not what I want. That will specify the row to use as index names. I want data that's before that row.

Comment: May be you can provide us with a sample of your meta data.

Comment: Is it only one specific cell that you want to read the metadata from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(filepath)

# you may want to set a correct row and column 
meta_data = xl.book.sheet_by_index(0).cell_value(0,0) 

skiprows = 5 # set it accordnigly...

df = xl.parse(0, skiprows=skiprows, parse_cols="B, D:I") \
       .dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Comment: what if we need to use xlrd module to skip the rows with the use of pandas ? How do we achieve it

Comment: @user3521180, `pd.ExcelFile` does use `xlrd` under the hood.